# Nginx proxy with node. weird rewrites when ran on port 80

Tags: node.js, docker, nginx

```
location  /api{
    rewrite /api(.*) $1 break;
    proxy_pass http://api;
}
```

so I have a node server running inside a container and using Nginx as a proxy it works fine if the container listens on any other port than 80. But when on 80 it only rewrites/reroutes two routs /api/v1/vendors and /api/v1/products to /v1/vendors/ and /v1/products/. but all other routes work fine. and the issue is fixed when I append a trailing / to /api/v1/vendors and /api/v1/products. can anyone explain why this might be happening? and it also fixes itself when I change the name of the routes even taking the s off works
you can try this behavior on  https://api.oroshops.com/api/v1/vendors and https://api.oroshops.com/api/v1/vendors/
you can try this behavior on  https://api.oroshops.com/api/v1/users and https://api.oroshops.com/api/v1/users/

Comment: You're only listing your location rewrite, but your problem lies elsewhere. There's also conflicting statements: if you truly believe the problem is at port 80, then your examples are flawed as they use https, which is port 443. It's very likely a 301 redirect is in play, but without seeing the entire context that applies to these routes, it's anyone's guess.

Comment: so today it started happening on all ports so the port is not an issue but why this one specific route. if I rename it it works for a while but then the same thing starts happening. and one more thing the /vendors route is the most used route that might be doing it?